# How to evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} i \binom{n-i}{k-1}$ to get $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I evaluate the following summation using `mma` (Version: 11.2.0.0):
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} i \binom{n-i}{k-1}$$

```
Sum[i Binomial[n - i, k - 1], {i, 1, n - k + 1}]
```

I get the result

> (n (1 + n) Binomial[-1 + n, -1 + k])/(k (1 + k))

which is
$$\frac{n (n+1) \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{k (k+1)}.$$

Why does it not simply it to $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

How to guide it to give $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

Comment: This may make it more obvious but it does not go all the way to the desired result: `FullSimplify[Sum[i*Binomial[n - i, k - 1], {i, 1, n - k + 1}], 
 Assumptions -> {Element[{n, k}, Integers], n >= k > 1}]`

Comment: It seems that MMA thinks `Gamma` is simpler than `Binomial`.